# Hover drop down menus closing before selection in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, cfml

disclaimer: I am very new to all coding, so TIA for your patience...

I was tasked with getting some pages working that I did not create and the person that made it is no longer an employee. I have them working ok in Chrome and Firefox, but not Internet Explorer.  The portion of the page that is not working are the dropdown menus which display on a mouseover and are for selecting how data in a map is displayed (populated via jQuery).  In IE when you click on a drop down menu to open it to view selections you can view them, but as soon as you move your mouse cursor the menu closes, so you can’t select anything.  If you hold the mouse button down you can view the whole menu, but releasing the mouse button or moving the mouse just causes the drop down to close without a selection.

I’ve been trying to research what could be causing the problem, and from what I can gather it could be an issue with jQuery and/or with CSS settings (z-index, or top?)  I’ve tried changing the CSS settings but can’t elicit any change in the drop down staying open for longer.  I’m a bit overwhelmed with this one and if someone could help point me towards what might be the underlying issue so I can research more specifically, that would be very much appreciated.

I will try to post the areas that I think are the relevant code (I can also post page links if need-be), I’ve left notes in here in case they are helpful as they were left from previous coder:

**CSS**:

```
<style type="text/css">
#legend:hover div 
        {left:-60px !important;top:28px}
#linkdiv:hover div 
        {left:50px !important;top:24px}
#navstatus 
        {font-weight:bold;vertical-align:middle}
.dynamicdropdown {
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    top:100%;
    z-index:5
}
#mapnavbox  {position:relative
            ;z-index:5
            ;text-align:left
            ;background-color:#F2FBFA
            ;padding:4px
            ;border:1px solid #666666
            ;width: 99%
            ;height:24px
            ;clear:both
            }   
.mapnav     {position:relative
            ;text-align:center
            ;background-color:#F2FBFA
            ;padding:4px
            ;width: 150px
            ;float:right
            ;z-index: 1000;
            }   
/*on hover over mapnav elements, bring div children back from banishment to off-stage left. */
.mapnav:hover div
            {left:0px; top:24px}
/*banish mapnav div child to off-stage left. */
.hiddenmenu {background-color:#F2FBFA !important
            ;border:solid #666666 1px
            ;position:absolute
            ;z-index: 1000
            ;top:100%
            ;left:-9999px /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */}                   

</style>
```

**Code for the hover menu/drop down section**:

```
<div id='params' class='mapnav' > 
        <strong>Change Parameter</strong>
<div class="hiddenmenu" style="height:200px">

<!---Setup the form fields for data selection--->

<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" >
<cfoutput>
     <select name="dddmon" class="dynamicdropdown" id="dddmon" >
     <option value="0" >Month</option>
           <cfloop from="1" to="12" step="1" index="selmon" >
               <option value="#selmon#" >#MonthAsString(selmon)#</option>
          </cfloop>
</select>

   <select name="myear" id="myear" class="dynamicdropdown">
   <option value = "0">Year</option>
        <cfloop query="availableyears" >
            <option value="#year#">#year#</option>
       </cfloop>
</select>

<select name="wqparm_sel" class="dynamicdropdown" id="wqparm_sel">
     <optgroup label="Parameters:">
     <option value="1" selected="selected">Bottom DO (mg/l)</option>
     <option value="2">Secchi Depth (meters)</option>
     <option value="3">Salinity (ppt)</option>
     <option value="4">Water Temperature (°F)</option>
     <option value="5">pH</option>
     …
     Etc.
     …
     </optgroup>
</select>
                </cfoutput> 

<input name="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" 
                onClick="populateMap(jQuery('#dddmon').val(),jQuery('#myear').val(),jQuery('#wqparm_sel').val()); showData(); getmyLegend(); ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'SubmitButton', eventAction: 'click', eventLabel: 'CurrentConditions', eventValue: 1});"/>
      </form>
```

Any insight or guidance would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty common with Internet Explorer, it's a bug that most likely doesn't have a pure-CSS fix, at least that I'm aware of. You could try to do a replacement of your select with custom items, but I think a little javascript would go a long way here. Using CSS to show/hide the menu, while in IE, gave me problems when recreating this. Added javascript for stopping event propagation per `<select>` ID's and showing/hiding the menu, and it works great.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mapnav').mouseover(function() {
    $('.hiddenmenu').show();
  });

  $('.hiddenmenu').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $('#dddmon, #myear, #wqparm_sel').mouseleave(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```css
.dynamicdropdown {
  height: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 5
}

.mapnav {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F2FBFA;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 150px;
  /* float: right; */
  z-index: 1000;
}

/*.mapnav:hover div {
   left: 0px;
   top: 24px 
}*/

.hiddenmenu {
  background-color: #F2FBFA !important;
  border: solid #666666 1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 100%;
  /* left: -9999px; */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='params' class='mapnav'>
  <strong>Change Parameter</strong>

  <div class="hiddenmenu" style="height:200px">
    <!---Setup the form fields for data selection--->
    <form name="form2" id="form2" method="post">
      <cfoutput>
        <select name="dddmon" class="dynamicdropdown" id="dddmon">
          <option value="0">Month</option>
          <option value="#selmon#">#MonthAsString(selmon)#</option>
        </select>

        <select name="myear" id="myear" class="dynamicdropdown">
          <option value="0">Year</option>
          <cfloop query="availableyears">
            <option value="#year#">#year#</option>
          </cfloop>
        </select>

        <select name="wqparm_sel" class="dynamicdropdown" id="wqparm_sel">
          <optgroup label="Parameters:">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Bottom DO (mg/l)</option>
            <option value="2">Secchi Depth (meters)</option>
            <option value="3">Salinity (ppt)</option>
            <option value="4">Water Temperature (°F)</option>
            <option value="5">pH</option>
            … Etc. …
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </cfoutput>

      <input name="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" onClick="populateMap(jQuery('#dddmon').val(),jQuery('#myear').val(),jQuery('#wqparm_sel').val()); showData(); getmyLegend(); ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'SubmitButton', eventAction: 'click', eventLabel: 'CurrentConditions', eventValue: 1});"
      />
    </form>
```

Tested in IE11, IE10, and IE9. Probably works further back, so you can check that if needed. Here's the JSFiddle I was working in, if needed: http://jsfiddle.net/ts0wb0tz/7/

Comment: Thank you, @Scott O., I made your edits and it's still not working for me in IE...maybe there's something else in my code interfering with it? I'm getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseover' of null"
Here's a link in case it helps: http://eyesonthebay.dnr.maryland.gov/eyesonthebay/currentconditions.cfm

Comment: Yes, I had jQuery in the header, if I put it where it is in your code snippet the map didn't load. I moved the jQuery code as suggested, and the map loads but I'm still having the issue with the dropdown closing in IE. Thanks for your help, I had tried to do the stopPropagation thing earlier and didn't get very far

Comment: I'm not sure what the conflict is on your page, but in the example I provided, the issue is resolved using your markup. The event.stopPropagation is definitely at the heart of it, so you were on the right track. The browser's default events have to be halted to ensure it doesn't think a mouseover on an option in a select drop down triggers a mouseleave. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep at it :)

Comment: I found your problem. You didn't correctly apply the CSS changes that I made in addition to the javascript. I should have suggested that yesterday. You do not want to hide that menu via the 'left: -9999px;' method anymore, so get rid of that, looks like it was in two CSS files so that would explain the confusion. Line 22 in the file '/tools/gpsvisualizer.css' is a definition for .hiddenmenu, where that 'left: -9999px;' appears again. You also have an error on the on-page CSS for the page you linked. '    top: 100% /* left: -9999px; */. The 'top: 100%' portion is missing a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Scott O., you're a trooper! I don't have it live on the site, but when I correct the CSS error (added the missing semicolon so I'm assuming it's now 'seeing' the `display:none` but I had removed the 'left:-9999px' method onpage) the hover menu no longer appears in IE or Chrome. I also made the changes in the separate gpsvisualizer.css and still no hover menu in IE or Chrome. If you could see the `left: -9999px;` does it mean that the separate CSS file was overriding the onpage CSS (b/c I had changed that onpage)? I thought onpage CSS would override the other file

Comment: You're correct about overrides, think I just got myself confused as I was inspecting the page and disabling/enabling properties in the inspector. I'm confident I have it now. Didn't notice the $.noConflict() callout on the page til now. In the javascript code I provided, I call out to jquery using $, but with noConflict, that shorthand is disabled. Replace all of the '$' with 'jQuery' in the javascript portion of what I provided. I think that should take care of the rest.

Comment: I changed the $ to jQuery in just your portion, like this `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 <cfoutput>populateMap(#dddmon#,#myear#,#wqparm_sel#);</cfoutput>
jQuery('.mapnav').mouseover(function() {
jQuery('.hiddenmenu').show();
  });
jQuery('.hiddenmenu').mouseleave(function() {
jQuery(this).hide();
});
jQuery('#dddmon, #myear, #wqparm_sel').mouseleave(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});
});` and the mouseover menus are now working in Chrome, but the original problem with them in IE is still there - mouseover opens but select dropdowns close before you can select.

Comment: Changes live on site, except I didn't load any changes to the /tools/gpsvisualizer.css because it affects another page and the onpage CSS should override.

Comment: Alright well, I give up. Sorry! It's definitely a matter of some kind of CSS/JS conflict, the code I provided definitely will solve your problem, it's just extremely time consuming to try and navigate the issues on that page. Good luck.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your help, time, and effort! You've at least helped pinpoint where my likeliest issues are, so thanks!